# How to allow access to a folder in Magento root?

Tags: pdf, .htaccess

I recently upgraded to Magento 2.4.6. I've always had a folder named "PS" with pdf files in my magento root but now I can't access it. I noticed that this line from **RewriteRule .* /pub/$0[L]** my root .htaccess plays a part in blocking it? What changes in my .htaccess should I make to make the PS folder and it's pdf files available.

Comment: add your PS folder to pub that would be better solution

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/PS/
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do anything in Pub/,htaccess

you just need to add the new_dir_name under the pub/
And than just add the .htaccess
and add allow all permissions